# How to use += operator in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a very simple code as below.

```
myVal=""
for ((i=1 ;i<=5 ;i++))
do
    myVal+=" * "
    echo $myVal
done
```

Issue is:

1. I am not able to use `+=` in this shell script code.
2. When I am assing a `*` in varibale, it prints all files which are in my working directory.

Output:

```
*
* * 
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

Comment: with quotes? like `"$myVal"`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. I'm very new in shell

Comment: Quote every variable expansion until it doesn't do what you expect/want it to do, not the other way around.

Comment: Ok, let me try to do it.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this -- I always recommend running shell code through it and fixing what it spots *even before* you discover the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with `+=`, which is working fine; your `myVal` var has a sequence of asterisks, exactly as intended. But when you `echo` it, those asterisks are expanded into the file list. To prevent that, you need to quote the expansion:

```
echo "$myVal"
```

You should always quote expansions in the shell, unless you have a very good specific reason not to. Basically, any time you see a `$` without a double quote in front of it, you should stop and think and make sure you know what's happening in that code.